# jQuery Twitter Bootstrap Tab select

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I've been looking around the net and tried many examples but can't figure out why I can't show a specific tab thru jQuery. This is my tab html:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-inside-tabs" id="cartTabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#cart-tab" data-toggle="tab" class="cart-btn">Purchases</a></li>
  <li><a href="#cart-data-tab" data-toggle="tab" id="cart-data-btn" class="cart-btn">Data</a></li>
  <li><a href="#cart-pay-tab" data-toggle="tab" id="cart-pay-btn" class="cart-btn">Pay</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="cart-tab">
    Cart
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="cart-data-tab">
    Content data
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="cart-pay-tab">
    Content pay
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried a switch and the alert show up good, but doesn't activate the correct tab:

```
$('#cart-goon-btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!$(this).attr('disabled')){
        var current_tab = $('.tab-pane.active').attr('id');
        switch(current_tab){
            case 'cart-tab':
                $('#cartTabs li a').eq($('#cart-data-tab')).tab('show');
                alertify.alert('1')
            break;
            case 'cart-data-tab':
                //cart-pay-tab
                alertify.alert('2')
            break;
            case 'cart-pay-tab':
                //checkout
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Instead of calling `.tab('show')` on the `div` you want to be visible, try doing it on the `a` element that you would use to activate it:

```
$('a[href="#cart-data-tab"]').tab('show');
```

Or probably better yet, just do it by id:

```
$('#cart-data-btn').tab('show');
```

Comment: :D Works like a charm! Tks. In a few minutes I'll check it as the answer!

Comment: Also, the `alertify.js` plugin looks really nice -- thanks for leading me to it with your question!

Comment: Top one worked for me where the second one didn't. Which is fine considering my React framework :) Thanks

Comment: If you came here looking for a way to switch bootstrap tab from jquery, this would work: `$('a[href="#cart-data-tab"]').click()`